# Assigning value from vuex state as initial value for another parameter

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have an array of objects in my Vuex state and I want to get one of its values as default value for another parameter.  In this case, it is for `mainAccount`:

Example:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    AccountNums: [
      {
        label: 'Mister1',
        value: '1234567890'
      },
      {
        label: 'Mister2',
        value: '9876543210'
      }
    ],
   mainAccount: this.state.AccountNums[1].value   //this is where I want to use the val from the obj
}
```

However, I am getting an error:

```
Cannot read property 'state' of undefined
```

When I remove `this` keyword, I get a different error:

```
'state' is not defined
```

So how should I do this?
Please note that I need this `AccountNums` object inside my Vuex state since a lot will be accessing this object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot refer in that way because the `store` is not created yet, there is a workaround by declare your `accountNums` object outside first and just refer to it like below

```js
const accountNums = [
      {
        label: 'Mister1',
        value: '1234567890'
      },
      {
        label: 'Mister2',
        value: '9876543210'
      }
    ];
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    AccountNums: accountNums,
   mainAccount: accountNums[1].value   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is not unique to Vuex. Any time you define a JavaScript object, you can't reference other properties of the object inside the object definition. That's why you're getting the error messages--because you're referencing the object inside the object definition.

The solution is fairly simple. Define the `AccountNums` array separately, then reference it in your store object. Like this:

```
const AccountNums = [
  {
    label: 'Mister1',
    value: '1234567890'
  },
  {
    label: 'Mister2',
    value: '9876543210'
  }
]

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    AccountNums,
    mainAccount: AccountNums[1].value   //this refers to the const declared above
}
```